# Make Spinner click disabled if it contains only 1 item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

```
 String options[] = new String[3];
   // options[0] = "Select IVC Option";
    int i =0;
    IDataObject emailobject = inMemoryCache_getDataObject("EMAIL_CONTACT");
    IDataObject smsobject = inMemoryCache_getDataObject("SMS_CONTACT");
    IDataObject voicecallobject = inMemoryCache_getDataObject("VOICE_CONTACT");

    try {
        if(emailobject != null){
            options [i] = "Email";
            i++;
        }
        if(smsobject != null){
            options [i] = "SMS";
            i++;
        }
        if(voicecallobject != null){
            options [i] = "VoiceCall";
            i++;
        }

    }catch (Exception e){

    }Spinner ivcoptions; ivcoptions = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> x = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options);
    x.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ivcoptions.setAdapter(x);
```

I want the spinner click be disabled , if and only if the Spinner contains 1 item. 
I have tried with controlling with the string array length. But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable spinner item click event, you'd need to change the adapter, however if you only want to prevent the spinner from being clicked on, you can simply register a data observer on your adapter:

```
final Spinner ivcoptions = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
final ArrayAdapter<String> x = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options);
x.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// Register a data observer
x.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        if (x.getCount() == 1) {
            ivcoptions.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            ivcoptions.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
});

// Set your adapter
ivcoptions.setAdapter(x);
```